# Computer Assistance Program

Tags: java

The question states this: "The use of computers in education is referred to as computer ¬assisted instruction (CAI). Write a program that will help an elementary school student learn multiplication. Use a Random object to produce 2 positive 1-digit integers. The program will then prompt the user with a question, such as “How much is 6 times 7?”

The student then inputs the answer. Next, the program checks the student’s answer. If it is correct, display the message “Very Good!” and ask another multiple question. If the answer is wrong, display the message “No. Please try again.” And let the student try the same question repeatedly until the student finally gets it right. A separate method will be used to generate each new question. This method will be called once when the application begins execution and each time the user answers the question correctly."

Here is what I have thus far.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package programmingassignment5.pkg35;

/**
 *
 * @author Jeremy
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public abstract class ProgrammingAssignment535 extends JApplet implements ActionListener{
JTextField question, input;   
JLabel prompt;   
int answer, guess;   
String questionString; 
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
 public void init(){      
// set guess to a flag value indicating no user input 17      
     guess = -999;      
// create text fields and a label 20     
     question = new JTextField( 20 );     
     question.setEditable( false );      
     prompt = new JLabel( "Enter your answer: " );     
     input = new JTextField( 4 );     
     input.addActionListener( this );    
     // add components to applet 29      
     Container container = getContentPane();     
     container.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );      
     container.add( question );     
     container.add( prompt );    
     container.add( input );     
// generate a question 36      
     createQuestion();   
 }
   public void paint( Graphics g ){      
       super.paint( g );
   // determine whether response is correct 44     
   // if guess isn't flag value 45      
     if (guess != -999){
     if (guess != answer) 
     g.drawString( "No. Please try again.", 20, 70 );        
     else {
     g.drawString( "Very Good!", 20, 70 ); 
     createQuestion();
     }
     guess = -999;
    }
} 
    // verify the entered response 
   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){     
       guess = Integer.parseInt( input.getText() );
   // clear the text field     
       input.setText( "" );
  // display the correct response     
       repaint();
   }
    // create a new question and a corresponding answer
   public void createQuestion(){// get two random numbers between 0 and 9 73      
       int digit1 = ( int ) ( Math.random() * 10 );
       int digit2 = ( int ) ( Math.random() * 10 );
       answer = digit1 * digit2;
       questionString = "How much is " + digit1 + " times " + digit2 + " ?";
       // add to applet 81      
       question.setText( questionString );
   }
}  // end class
```

The only error that it is giving me is that the program is missing the main class.  Usually this is an easy fix but I cannot figure out how to implement it here without breaking everything any suggestions?

Comment: So, where's your `main` method?

Comment: Your program must have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: Argh beat me to it lol, you need your main method to start your program lol

Comment: I understand that it needs a main method. My issue is I have no clue where to put it here. Everywhere I try brings with it tons of errors.

Comment: @Jesper Every time I try to add public static void main(String[] args) i get an error saying that I'm referencing a non-static variable in a static context?

Comment: @JeremyBrooks, show what you have tried when you added a main method. All of the code you have shown already is really secondary to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need some basic "Hello World" kind of help with Swing. Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java).

There are many issues with your code (Why is your class Abstract? Why are you overriding paint?). Look up some swing tutorials. As for your main method problem, try something like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ProgrammingAssignment535 myApplet = new ProgrammingAssignment535();
            myApplet.init();
            myApplet.setVisible( true );
        }
    } );
}
```

You will also have to make the class not abstract.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I will look up some basic tutorials. As for making the class abstract netbeans showed an error saying that to use ActionListener that the class needed to be abstract?

Comment: @JeremyBrooks I suspect you misread that error message. When you first added the interface, you got an error saying you needed to either add the missing actionPerformed method OR make the class abstract.

Comment: you are correct I changed it from abstract and added your main argument.  When I did this the program built successfully but nothing appeared in netbeans other than the build success message.  Thank you for your help.  I think I might just start from scratch if you don't have anymore advice?  Thank you again though!